# Symfony 3.4 dynamic content on routes (listener ?)

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-3.4, symfony3.x

I would like to have dynamic content on several pages of my application. This content would be stored in my database and an admin could update it when ever he wants.

Is it possible to create a listener executed every time a route is called to check if there is content on the database for this route, then inject it in the template ?

Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

If you look up the Route It allows you to make more dynamic ones. I.e:

```
/**
 * @Route("/pages/{fieldname}/{value}
 */
public function pageContentAction(Request $request)
{
...
}
```

This way you can reuse the params and check the DB for content:

```
        $fieldName = $request->get('fieldname');
        $newValue = $request->get('value');

        $page = $em->getRepository('AppBundle:Pages')->findOneBy(
            array('fieldname' =>$fieldName,'value'=>$value)
        );
        if ($page == null){
            return new JsonResponse(['message'=>'Page Not Found'],404);
        }
```

Comment: Yeah I'm aware of that. I was looking for a way to add dynamic content base on route names. For example : on the page "index_users" the admin could set a custom explanatory text in DB to be show on the page. Its like a CMS but for symfony

Comment: @Kirk_ so? the answer above... In your method for route "index_users" you will get something from table eg.: "texts" and use findOneBy(["pageId" => "index_users"]);... and so on

Comment: @Kirk_ then maybe you're looking for routes loaded from a database instead? See https://symfony.com/doc/3.4/routing/routing_from_database.html

Comment: I'm more looking for a way to have a query running every time a route is executed. @Eakethet Adding the same code for all routes would not be the proper thing to do, and not the most maintenable solution.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to have a look at Dynamic Router (https://symfony.com/doc/master/cmf/bundles/routing/dynamic.html). It's part of the Symfony CMF package (http://cmf.symfony.com/) which is actually a way to build CMS for Symfony.